# How do we create a new product display for customeize product?

Tags: commerce

I have created a product called music now how to create a product display for the music product in drupal commerce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set this up manually, follow these steps:

1. Add a node type called *Product display*. Submit using the *Save and add fields* button.
2. Add a **Product Reference field** that uses an *Autocomplete text field* widget. Make the field required and allow an unlimited number of values (even if you only intend to use a single value for now).
3. Click over to the *Manage display* tab and ensure this field uses the ***Add to Cart form*** display formatter. You might also want to move around the product fields you see listed here.
4. Create a *Product display* referencing one of your products and examine the node's teaser and full page views. You may want to change the way product fields are displayed. To do this, you actually have to browse to your product type's *Manage display* page and update the display formatter settings there. You can only adjust the sort order and visibility of product fields through the content type edit pages, not the formatter settings.